# How to set the digest algorithm to MD5 in Jekyll 3?

Tags: jekyll

I'm in the process of migrating a fairly old Jekyll 2 to a recent Jekyll 3. I've realized that the default digest algorithm for the assets changed from MD5 to SHA, and that breaks all existing links to assets. For example, if someone shares the post on Facebook, the image URL is cached and will result in a broken image.

I'm trying to set the algorithm back to MD5, but I'm unable to find any usable info googling around. I've learned that assets are handled by jekyll-assets, which uses Sprockets under the hood. I think I need to configure it somehow, but I don't know how to access it via either the `_config.yml` or from `.rb` files.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version the algorithm type can't be configured in `jekyll-assets`, jekyll-assets only have: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-assets/blob/master/lib/jekyll/assets/liquid/tag/defaults/sha.rb where it sets:

```
def set_integrity
              digest = Sprockets::DigestUtils.integrity_uri(
                Digest::SHA384.digest(
                  @asset.to_s
                )
)
```

where you would need to use `Digest::MD5`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll live with the broken links then. I was hoping for a non-documented configuration option, but overriding this class seems too fragile to me.

Comment: @sashee the best strategy would be to ask for this feature in the Github repo and even better to try to make a pull request with it kg they want to add it